# Generate consistent hash of a UUID

Tags: javascript, node.js, guid

I want to generate a consistent hash of a UUID string such as `dcc549d8-bd0c-49c2-bff8-f6fa80fb7857`, preferably a number between 0 to N.

What is the best and fastest way to do it?

Update: I am thinking of using CRC32. Any pros/cons of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What kind of hash would you like? The 'best' choice might not be fastest and will depend on what you're using the hash for.

For md5, you could do:

```js
var crypto = require('crypto');

var md5sum = crypto.createHash('md5');
md5sum.update(uuid);
var b64 = md5sum.digest('base64')
```

You could then use a base64 library to convert it to a number if that's what you need.

Node crypto stuff, including other hashing algorithms that might be more appropriate for your case (md5 is faster but less secure), is documented here: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

Comment: I am just looking for single digit number between 0-9 so that I can route x% of requests to different servers based on this number.

Comment: How about using crc32?

Answer (score 5):

If thinking about the nature of UUID [example](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-math-exercise-23.php).
I would go in that direction.

```js
const INIT_NUMBER = 271;

function hash(uuid, N) {
  const x = uuid.split("-").reduce((a,b) => a ^ Number.parseInt(b, 16), INIT_NUMBER) ;
  return arguments.length === 1 ? x : x % N;
}

const a = hash("dcc549d8-bd0c-49c2-bff8-f6fa80fb7857");            
const b = hash("dcc549d8-bd0c-49c2-bff8-f6fa80fb7857", 256);

console.log(a, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using v4 UUID generation, all digits except for two already contain pseudorandom values, all you need to do is extract them to the form you want.

From the Spec:

```
4.4.  Algorithms for Creating a UUID from Truly Random or
      Pseudo-Random Numbers

   The version 4 UUID is meant for generating UUIDs from truly-random or
   pseudo-random numbers.

   The algorithm is as follows:

   o  Set the two most significant bits (bits 6 and 7) of the
      clock_seq_hi_and_reserved to zero and one, respectively.

   o  Set the four most significant bits (bits 12 through 15) of the
      time_hi_and_version field to the 4-bit version number from
      Section 4.1.3.

   o  Set all the other bits to randomly (or pseudo-randomly) chosen
      values.
```

To extract the pseudorandom values, we simply remove the first hex character (which contains the 4 most significant bits) of the third and fourth sections separated by "-" and convert it to the base you want. Because a UUID is always the same length, we can remove the same indexes each time (14 and 19).

Unfortunately, as Javascript only supports up to 32-bit integers, we need to feed `Number.parseInt` groups of 8 hex characters (32 bits) separately, then add the modulos to minimize bias.

Therefore, our code would be:

```
function parseUUID(uuid, N) {
    var pseudorandomBytes = uuid.substring(0, 14) + uuid.substring(15, 19) + uuid.substring(20); // Splice out the bytes which contain metadata
    pseudorandomBytes = pseudorandomBytes.replace(/-/g, ""); // Remove all dashes
    var accumulator = 0; // Accumulate the sums modulo N of every eight hex characters and the remainder
    pseudorandomBytes.match(/.{1,8}/g).forEach(function (a) { accumulator = (accumulator + (Number.parseInt(a, 16) % N)) % N; });
    return accumulator; // Return the result
}
```